# SVN - Cherry picking conflicts to resolve after branch reintegration

Tags: svn, merge, branch, rebase, cherry-pick

Following the methodology of short-lived feature branches, we have:
- Trunk
- Branch A (off Trunk)
- Branch B (off Trunk)
- There are nightly rebases from Trunk to both branches.

Now, development in Branch A is complete. Branch A was re-integrated back to Trunk. No issues or conflicts. Next comes the rebase from Trunk (with Branch A reintegrated) into Branch B. There are conflicts. This is understandable and expected.

However, to resolve those conflicts, I need developers from 2 different teams (don't ask me why we have server and client code in the same trunk, but we do)

But I cannot cherry-pick conflicted files for Team 1 separately from conflicted files for Team 2, since Branch A **Reintegration commit lumps everything into just 1 commit**.

In other words, how can I resolve a rebase conflict (off a reintegration commit) in 2 steps, but 2 different people?

What we have been doing so far was have the 2 teams work on resolving their conflicts separately, and then Team 1 sends all their resolved files to Team 2, and Team 2 commits the resolution.